# What's different between sql script with embedded or separated where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I want a report that show me which `HumanResources.Employee` weren't in relation with `Sales.OrderHeader`. I must use `RIGHT/LEFT OUTER JOIN` but in filtering we have two choise(use where statement in join or in where experssion).

I used this code:

```
SELECT 
    E.EmployeeID,
    E.FirstName,
    E.LastName,
    O.OrderHeaderID,
    O.OrderDate
FROM 
    Sales.OrderHeader O
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee E ON O.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID 
    AND O.OrderHeaderID IS NULL
```

and:

```
SELECT 
    E.EmployeeID,
    E.FirstName,
    E.LastName,
    O.OrderHeaderID,
    O.OrderDate
FROM 
    Sales.OrderHeader O
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee E ON O.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE 
    O.OrderHeaderID IS NULL
```

I expected show me same result but first code shown:

```
EmployeeID|  FirstName|   LastName| OrderHeaderID
-----------+----------+------------+-----------
     1     |    نوری    |  محمد    |    NULL
     2     |    فربدی    |   حسن   |    NULL
     3     |    صباغی    |  محمد   |    NULL
     4     |    مرادی    |  احمد   |    NULL
     10    |    احمدی    |   حسن   |    NULL
     11    |   بیرونی    |  ساسان  |    NULL
```

and second code show this result (correct result):

```
EmployeeID|  FirstName|   LastName| OrderHeaderID
-----------+----------+------------+-----------
     10    |    احمدی    |   حسن   |    NULL
     11    |   بیرونی    |  ساسان  |    NULL
```

I didn't find that what reasons are behind these results.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes are different. Second does what you described. Try to join based on employeId (records are in relation when they have same EmployeeID) then filter only results where right side is empty (no relation).

First code is trying to do the join based on equal EmployeeID and  O.OrderHeaderID IS NULL. So you're saying that relation is when records have same EmployeeID and OrderHeaderID is null in table. So it is different relation.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think `LEFT JOIN` is easier for most people to follow.  It means "keep all the rows in the *first* table, along with matching values from the second".  I admit that for people whose native language reads from right to left, this might be less natural.

Second, the `ON` clause in the outer join is very easy to follow.  It says to keeps *all* the rows, even when there is no match.  So, your condition is `O.OrderHeaderID IS NULL`.  All the rows are kept in the second table (`Employee`), regardless of how this evaluates.

You know that the right solution is to put the condition in the `WHERE` clause, so there is no need to go over that.

Comment: In HumanResources.Employee I have just 2 record with haven't any relation with Sales.OrderHeader. I say these two script must return same result. My question is EmployeeID 1,2,3,4 have gotten from where?? because I have just EmployeeID 10,11 that haven't any relation.EmployeeID 1,2,3,4 have relation and shouldn't shown as NULL.